# Unable To Step Into a WCF Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, sharepoint

For some reason I am unable to step into my WCF Service. It IS located in the solution with the client. I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9986861/wcf-beginner-tutorial-unable-to-debug-step-into) but it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: Did you tried anything? Read [faq] and [ask]

Comment: Where is the service deployed? SharePoint? Which version?

Comment: It is Sharepoint 2010. This is just on my Dev machine. I apologize I'm extremely green on Sharepoint. I looked at properties on the service project, and it says for the destination server: Default Web Site/service_deploy. Is there somewhere else to look?

Comment: I also have the WCF Service and the client set to debug. Both are set to build also.

Answer (score 0):

You can launch the service after adding the line `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch()` in your code. This will popup a window asking you to select which debugger you want to use.

If it doesn't pop the window, you are certainly not running the code you think you are. Often it can be because of a mismatched configuration, or a misunderstood parameter